# Error: Request failed with status code 400. Differences between sending in POSTMAN and in the application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, postman

In POSTMAN it works:

```
1) url: https://app/login
2) method: POST
3) body
4) x-www-form-urlencoded
5)username: ****,
password: ****,
grant_type: 'password',
client_secret: '****',
client_id: '****'
```

In the function `submit` method POST, when the form is submit, it does not work. I have error:

> xhr.js?b50d POST https://app/login 400 (Bad Request)
>
> Error: Request failed with status code 400
>       at createError (createError.js?2d83)
>       at settle (settle.js?467f)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d)

In tab `Network` in `response` I have:

> {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client credentials were
>   not found in the headers or body"}

**Login**

```
class Login extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }

  handle = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  submit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const body1 = {
      username: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      grant_type: 'password',
      client_secret: '****',
      client_id: '****'
    }

    axios({ 
      method: 'post', 
      url: 'https://app/login', 
      body: body1, 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
      }) 
      .then(res => { 
        if (res.status === 200) {
          console.log(res)
        } 
      }).catch(err => { 
        console.error(err);
      });

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <form action="" method="post" onSubmit={this.submit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input type="email" required  name="email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handle}  />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password"name="password"
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={this.handle}  />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">Log</button>
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

What are the differences between sending in POSTMAN and in the application? Contents of the body convert to a string?

Comment: Are you sure it's not an issue with CORS ? Chrome packaged apps can have cross domain permissions. When you install Postman it promts you that this app will access any domain.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski I don't have any errors from CORS. Only: `400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski If it was a problem with `CORS`, I would probably have an error. Maybe I need to convert something? Something like: JSON.stringify ()?

Comment: according to axios docs you post with a `data` key instead of a `body`

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski 
I changed `body` to `data`, but I have the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is stating in the Content-Type that the body will be URL string encoded, but in the body it is given a JavaScript object.  It doesn't seem like the Axios client turns that body object into a url-encoded value (ie from `{a: 5, b: 2}` to `"a=5&b=2"`). The code needs a function convert that. A popular one is [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs).

Otherwise your data will probably be turned into a string with the `.toString()` method which will give you `"[object Object]"`, you should be able to see this in the network tab of the developer tools.

Comment: change `body` to `data`? I have to use `parse` or `stringify`?

Comment: If the server can accept it, you can change the Content-Type to application/json

Answer (score 2):

Axios handles error differently.

To find out what really is the issue.

You should use `error.request` to check if the request you made has error

and use `error.response` to get the error feedback from the server

```js
  axios({ 
      method: 'post', 
      url: 'https://app/login', 
      body: body1, 
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
      }) 
      .then(res => { 
        if (res.status === 200) {
          console.log(res)
        } 
      }).catch(err => { 
          if(err.request){
              console.log(err.request)
          }
          if(err.response){
              console.log(err.response)
          }
      });
```

Comment: thanks I was able to debug my error using this

Answer (score 0):

**Localhost:3000/api/products 404 Error**
You did not create res.get("/api/products") on server.js or you did not set the proxy. check below for proxy setting.

**Proxy error: could not proxy request /api/products**
Check this:

1. frontend/package.json

   {
   "name": "frontend",
   "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
   ...
   }
2. stop running frontend and backend
3. Run backend first

   npm start
4. Then frontend

   cd frontend
   npm start

Answer (score 0):

The code is stating in the Content-Type that the body will be URL string encoded, but in the body it is given a JavaScript object. It doesn't seem like the Axios client turns that body object into a url-encoded value (ie from {a: 5, b: 2} to "a=5&b=2"). The code needs a function convert that. A popular one is qs.

```
npm i qs;
import qs as qs;

axios.post(your_url,
  qs.strigify({
      key1:value1,
      key2:value2,
 }),{
headers:{
   'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
}
})
```